# How to hide and unhide a page of XtraTabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How to hide and unhide a page of XtraTabControl? I have several tabs in XtraTabControl how can I hide and unhide them on button click? I am using c# and XtraTabControl is a DevExpress control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please use the [XtraTabPage.PageVisible](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabPage_PageVisibletopic) property:

```
xtraTabPage.PageVisible = !xtraTabPage.PageVisible;
```